# Customize file name when upload to laravel storage

Tags: laravel

I want to save image path & name to database, but laravel always randomize the file name that I uploaded.

This is my code:

```
if ($request->has('photo')) {
   $file = $request->photo;
   $employee->photo_file_name = $employee->id . now();
   $path = $file->store('public/images');
   $employee->photo_file_type = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $employee->photo_file_path = $path;
}
$employee->save();
```

It's already working, but the file name that stored to `public/images` is random, it makes the name for `photo_file_path` & `photo_file_name` different. What I want is both `photo_file_name` and `photo_file_path` have the same file name.

Example:

```
photo_file_name      |  photo_file_type |  photo_file_path 
employee_1-2021.jpg  |  .jpg            |  public/images/employee_1-2021.jpg
```

Comment: The Laravel manual has a page on [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads) and a section on [Specifying A File Name](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name), doesn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

**Here** you can get the file name with relative path. E.g /public/images/employee_1-2021.jpg

```
$file_path = '/public/images';
if ($request->has('photo')) {
    $file = $request->photo;
    $original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $original_filename_arr = explode('.', $original_filename);
    $filename = $original_filename_arr[0];
    $file_ext = end($original_filename_arr);
    $file_path_name = 'employee_'.$employee->id. '2021.' . $file_ext;
    if ($file->storeAs($file_path, $file_path_name)) {
        $relative_path = $file_path . '' . $file_path_name;
    }
    return $relative_path;
}
```